# Как удалить загруженные ранее картинки с папки?

Tags: php

Картинка: в бд заношу её имя, директорию, тип.
Создал 1 инпут и кнопку "delete". Удаляю по id записи

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);
    $query = "DELETE FROM Video WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

При таком коде я удаляю всю запись с базы данных, но сама картинка в папке остаётся(логично). Скажите, как вместе с записью в бд удалить и саму картинку с папки ?

Comment: У вас наверняка есть путь в БД. Получаете   `$query = "SELECT path FROM Video WHERE id='$id'";` Путь должен быть полным /var/.../YOUR_SITE/PATH/TO/PICTURE.extension  и смотрите ответ Palmervan по ссылке  Darth